# one of the two input fields is required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields one is `file` the other is `textarea`

```
<input class="input_field" type="file" name="title" />
<textarea class="input_field" name="info"></textarea>
```

User has to either upload a file or type text. If the user leaves blank both of the inputs, it should say like "*choose a file* or *type info*" if he/she fills both, it is ok.

My JQuery:

```
$(function(){
       $(".input_field").prop('required',true);
});
```

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/651/). How can we implement something like `if else` condition to make it required one of the fields?

Comment: try manual code with alert message

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/652/

I modified your code to each all the elements with a class of input_field when the form is submitted.

```
$(function(){
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var failed = false;
           $(".input_field").each(function() {
               if (!$(this).val()) {
                    failed = true;   
               }
           });

            console.log(failed);
            if (failed === true) {  
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, there are only two possible conditions:

- if either one field or both fields are filled, user passes validation
- if no fields are filled, user fails validation

This can be easily done by checking for the value of either input. As long as one is not empty, user passes the test. This if/else condition can be written as:

```
if($('input[type="file"].input_field').val() || $('textarea.input_field').val()) {
    // Passed validation 
} else {
    // Failed validation
}
```

A simple pattern to check for errors is to create an error flag, which will be raised when one or more validation checks have failed. You evaluate this error flag at the end of the script before manual form submission:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Perform validation
        var error = false;

        if($('input[type="file"].input_field').val() || $('textarea.input_field').val()) {
            alert('Passed validation');
            error = false;
        } else {
            alert('Please fill up one field');
            error = true;
        }

        // Check error flag before submission
        if(!error) $(this)[0].submit();
    });
});
```

See working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/LEZ4r/653/

Comment: This isn't very scalable - if the OP wants to add another input to the form then the JS will need to be altered as well.

Comment: @DavidJones Well, the OP only asked about validating two fields, and I suppose he isn't looking for scalability. If you want to talk about scalability, you will have to refactor your code to consider pairs of `.input_field` instead of simply iterating through all of them at once. In short, without further knowing what context is OP intending to use the code in, we will not know if scalability will ever be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check inside your form If atleast one is done break the loop and go for submit else return false

```js
$(function(){
  $('form').on('submit',function(e){
    var doneOnce = false;
    $(this).children().each(function(){
      if($(this).val()){
        doneOnce = true;
        return false;//return false will break the .each loop
      }
    });
    alert(doneOnce)
    if(!doneOnce){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="input_field" type="file" name="title" />
  <textarea class="input_field" name="info"></textarea>
  <input type=submit />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write codes in Javascript to validate form. You have to make an onclick or onsubmit function, and the function will check whether any of the input field is empty. You can write something like the following code:

```
<script>
  function validateForm() {
    var fstname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lstname=document.getElementById("lname").value;

    if(fstname===null || fstname===""){
        alert("Plese choose a file.");
        return false;
    }
    else if(lstname===null || lstname===""){
      alert("Plese type file info.");
      return false;  
    }
    else{ 
        return confirm("Your file: "+fstname+" and it of type "+lstname);

    }
}
```

```
<body>
   <form action="text.php" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    First Name: <input type="file" id="fname" name="FirstName">
    Last Name: <input type=text" id="lname" name="LastName"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   <form> 

</body>
```